# MongoDB map reduce - group and find top N

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

An , and collection called test

Consider this test collection, in which an airport is identified by AirportID:

```
{ AirportID:"1001", delayMinutes :"15.0" },
{ AirportID:"1004", delayMinutes :"3.0" },
{ AirportID:"1001", delayMinutes :"20.0" },
{ AirportID:"1002", delayMinutes :"6.0" },
{ AirportID:"1002", delayMinutes :"25.0" },
{ AirportID:"1004", delayMinutes :"55.0" },
```

I want to group it together and list the top 2 from that list.

This is the query I tried:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$AirportID", delayMinutes: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
  { $sort: { delayMinutes: -1 } }
])
```

But it didn't work for me

Comment: The querry I use in here: 
db.test.aggregate({ $group: { _id: "$AirportID", delayMinutes: { $sum: 1 } } }, { $sort: { delayMinutes: -1 } })

Comment: Please post your query into the question instead of posting in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Besides, did you consider the rank for querying Top 2? For scenarios such as there are multiple AirportID with the highest number of delays. There are 2 types of ranks: [`$rank`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/) and [`$denseRank`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/denseRank/).

Comment: I want to group it together and list the top 2 from that list

Comment: The query that is now in your question will return the airports sorted by number of delays, not by the sum of the delay. If you want the sum of the delay use `delayMinutes: { $sum: {$toInt: '$delayMinutes'} }`.

Comment: If you want only to results, use `$limit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, you just need to do 2 additional things:

1. Add a `$limit` stage at the end to only return 2 results
2. Cast the `delayMinutes` to a number using `$toDecimel` or `$toDouble`, note that any invalid string value will make this stage fail.

Overall this is what it'll look like:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$AirportID",
      delayMinutes: {
        $sum: {
          "$toDouble": "$delayMinutes"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      delayMinutes: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gKwnSAhckXs)

Comment: I want to put the condition for $delayMinutes > "15.0", where should I put it?

Comment: you should put it before the group stage, in a `$match` stage